# Rewrite url via htaccess on apache server

Tags: .htaccess, opencart-3

I have a url which is
[www.domain.com/index.php?route=ticketsystem/generatetickets](http://www.domain.com/index.php?route=ticketsystem/generatetickets)
I want people who type in the url [www.domain.com/contact](http://www.domain.com/contact) to be redirected to the page index.php?route=ticketsystem/generatetickets  however have the url bar still show /contact is that possible via htaccess and if so how? I tried the below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule contact /index.php?route=ticketsystem/generatetickets [L,QSA]
```

Comment: For your given rules please do let us know what's not working?

Answer (score 0):

For your shown attempts, please try following .htaccess rules file. Make sure your index.php and .htaccess files are present in same directory/folder. Also better to use `&` rather than using `/` for query string.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ index.php?route=ticketsystem&generatetickets [QSA,NC,L]
```